# Zonal Statistic Tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, zonal-statistics

In ArcGIS, I have a grid 5x5km (I have it both in vector and raster formats) I want to calculate, based on this grid, the zonal statistic (MEAN) of a raster 30x30m pixel size. The raster overlaps perfectly the reference grids, the output (which I set in the environments/Raster_analysis to be 5X5km) is somehow shifted of about half a grid (which does not allow me to transfer the MEAN data from the raster to the feature grid, throughout RasterToPoint and then join by location).